# Setting GTalk status using Java - GAE/J

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, google-talk

I want to set the status GTalk through my Java program.

My application will run on Google App Engine/Java. And will use XMPP API.

Is it possible? And how can I do that? Some code example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The App Engine XMPP API does not support this.  You can only send/receive messages and check if a user is online.</strike>

This is actually possible now! See [the updated docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html#Sending_Application_Status)!